# Simple mutex application isn't working correctly?

Tags: c, winapi, mutex

Consider this code:

```
#include  <Windows.h>

test(HANDLE*hB0)
{
    printf("hello "), ReleaseMutex(*hB0);
}
main()
{
    HANDLE hB0;
        CreateThread(0,0,test,(hB0=CreateMutex(NULL,true,NULL),&hB0),0,0),
        WaitForSingleObject(hB0, INFINITE),
        printf("world!");
}
```

I'm expecting to get hello world! but I'm just getting world! instead. Any ideas why?

I tried with second parameter to CreateMutex both true & false but it is still not working.

Comment: Where did you find that code? It's not correct at all.

Comment: @KenWhite I wrote it - what's wrong with it - I want to wait till I fetch some data in the thread.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the code is incorrect, but I'm not well versed in the Windows API.  It does, however, exhibit grotesque and wholly unnecessary (over)use of the comma operator.

Comment: You cannot wait for an mutex you already own. Wait for the thread to die instead.

Comment: @tkausl The thread will sleep n amount of seconds before it dies and I want to let it do its job while spawning other threads however I need to wait in-before the thread fetches some data from the pointer I gave her.

Comment: Then you might need to use a condition variable to signal your main thread.

Comment: your code containing many errors. `ReleaseMutex(*hB0)` by your signature, you not check error code after this call, but it `ERROR_NOT_OWNER` (*Attempt to release mutex not owned by caller*), the `WaitForSingleObject(hB0, INFINITE)` just return because thread is owner of mutex

Comment: @RbMm beat me to it. Besides the obvious issues mentioned in that comment and the answer below, every single WinAPI call should be error checked. Your code does none. In addition, it reads like you wrote it as a poor entry in an obfuscated code contest.  It's not really obfuscated, but it's written so badly that I wouldn't hire someone who presented it as a code sample. It's a bad habit to try to be cute and save keystrokes instead of writing readable code and failing to add error checks. Your `test` function also is improperly implemented; it should be returning a DWORD.

Comment: Also, don't ignore the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread): *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management rather than `CreateThread` and `ExitThread`"*.

Comment: @KenWhite "*Your `test` function also is improperly implemented; it should be returning a DWORD*" - not only that, but it needs the `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) calling convention, and an `LPVOID` (`void*`) input parameter. The signature is completely wrong for `CreateThread()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [`CreateMutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw) function

> The thread that owns a mutex can specify the same mutex in repeated
>   wait function calls without blocking its execution

in call

```
hB0=CreateMutex(NULL,true,NULL)
```

the `bInitialOwner = TRUE` so your current thread own the mutex, as result `WaitForSingleObject(hB0, INFINITE)` just return without blocking execution.

from another side if thread, which not own mutex, call `ReleaseMutex` - will be error returned `ERROR_NOT_OWNER` - *Attempt to release mutex not owned by caller.* or native status `STATUS_MUTANT_NOT_OWNED` *An attempt to release a mutant object was made by a thread that was not the owner of the mutant object.* - but you not check function result and error code.

also because you define `test(HANDLE*hB0)` - you need call `ReleaseMutex(*hB0);` instead `ReleaseMutex(hB0);`. however better pass `hB0` handle direct to thread as argument, instead pointer `&hB0` to handle.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - but what you need implement ?

Comment: I need to wait for thread to fetch some data I pass as a pointer. Basically in current case it need to print "hello world!".

Comment: But I can't relay on the thread handle to wait. Since in my case the thread will continue working afterwards separate from the main thread.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - exist many ways for do this. say pass event to thread, when thread finished it work - it set event. your main thread wait on this event. but in this case ask separate question - your current question - what is error in my concrete code. i give answer for it

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - so you use here wrong object - need use event (`CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL)`), instead mutant

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions: You don't depend on execution order of the thread. If you need things to happen in a certain order, don't use a thread. Threads are designed to do something in the background while your main thread continues. If your main thread is going to wait, then do the work in the main thread and don't use a background thread.